# Can anybody help me getting current activity's layout and views via adb, if the screen is a Webview?

Tags: xml, layout, webview, adb, dump

As both commands, `adb shell uiautomator dump` or `adb shell dump --compressed`` doesn't work with Webview Layout.

Comment: Be more specific about what you want to achieve.

Comment: I wanted to use xml of the current screen which i am extracting it using adb command. Since this screen has a webview element which doesn't give xml/data of its child elements when i use **adb shell uiautomator dump** so for that case i am using **adb shell uiautomator dump --compressed** that gives me the xml of all elements of the webview screen i.e elements present inside a webview element too. But the problem is in some webview screens i am not getting xml of all elements of the screen using event --compressed command. Can any body help me fetching the xml those elements?

Comment: Webviews don't have a layout, they have a DOM. If you want to get access to the DOM you need to call `WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);` within the app and then you can connect from Chrome on your PC to the Webview in your app and explore the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Some `WebView`s can do it. This is **Chrome** showing YouTube's home page and using [dump](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/blob/master/tools/dump) (*you can probably do the same with `uiautomator` but this one is simpler*)

```
dump
```

result:

```
android.widget.FrameLayout
   android.widget.FrameLayout
      android.webkit.WebView  Home - YouTube
         android.view.View
            android.view.View player-container-id
            android.view.View app
               android.view.View header-bar
                  android.view.View
                     android.view.View
                        android.view.View home-icon
                           android.widget.Image
                     android.widget.Button  Search YouTube
                     android.view.View
                        android.widget.Button  Account
               android.widget.TabWidget
                  android.view.View  Home
                     android.view.View
                        android.widget.Image
                     android.view.View  Home
                  android.view.View  Shorts
                     android.view.View
                        android.widget.Image
                     android.view.View  Shorts
                  android.view.View  Library
                     android.view.View
                        android.widget.Image
                     android.view.View  Library
               android.view.View
                  android.view.View filter-chip-bar
                     android.widget.TabWidget
                        android.view.View  Explore
                           android.view.View
                              android.widget.Image
                           android.widget.TextView  Explore
                        android.view.View
                        android.view.View  All
                        android.view.View  Live
                        android.view.View  Music
                        android.view.View  Gaming
                        android.view.View  History
                        android.view.View  Amber Heard <-------- see this in DOM below
                        android.view.View  Trailers
                        android.view.View  Thrillers
                        android.view.View  Indoor games and sports
                        android.view.View  Wildlife
                        android.view.View  Eating
                        android.view.View  Machines
                        android.view.View  Comedies
                        android.view.View  Cats
                        android.view.View  Dogs
                        android.view.View  Debates
                        android.view.View  Baseball
                        android.view.View  Gardening
                        android.view.View  Game shows
                        android.view.View  Comedy
                        android.view.View  Recently uploaded
...
```

and you can also open Chrome Dev Tools and explore the DOM tree, and see the corresponding elements

```
...
<div class="chip-container"><span class="typography-title-1 chip-text">Amber Heard</span></div>
...
```